# STM32 MCU GCC Compilation behavior

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, enums, stm32

I have some misunderstanding about MCU GCC compilation behavior regarding function that return other things that 32bits value.

```
MCU: STM32 L0 Series (STM32L083)
GCC : gcc version 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907] (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2018-q2-update)
```

My code is optimized for size (with option `-Os` ). In my understanding, this will allow the gcc to use implicit `-fshort-enums` in order to pack enums.

I have two enum var, 1-byte wide :

```
enum eRadioMode         radio_mode // (@ 0x20003200)
enum eRadioFunction     radio_func // (@ 0x20003201)
```

And a function :

```
enum eRadioMode radio_get_mode(enum eRadioFunction _radio_func);
```

When i call this bunch of code :

```
radio_mode = radio_get_mode(radio_func);
```

It will produce this bunch of ASM at compile time:

```
; At this point :
;   r4 value is 0x20003201 (Address of radio_func)

7820        ldrb    r0, [r4, #0]            ; GCC treat correctly r4 as a pointer to 1 byte wide var, no problem here
f7ff ffcd   bl  80098a8 <radio_get_mode>    ; Call to radio_get_mode()
4d1e        ldr r5, [pc, #120]              ; r5 is loaded with 0x20003200 (Address of radio_mode)
6028        str r0, [r5, #0]                ; Why GCC use 'str' and not 'strb' at this point ?
```

The last line here is the problem : The value of `r0`, return value of `radio_get_mode()`, is stored into address pointed by `r5`, as a 32bit value.
Since `radio_func` is 1 byte after `radio_mode`, its value is overwritten by the second byte of `r0` (that is always 0x00 since enum is only 1 byte wide).

As my function `radio_get_mode` is declared as returning 1 single byte, why GCC doesn't use instruction `strb` in order to save this single byte into the address pointed by `r5` ?

I have tried :

- `radio_get_mode()` as returning `uint8_t` : `uint8_t radio_get_mode(enum eRadioFunction _radio_func);`
- Forcing cast to `uint8_t` : `radio_mode = (uint8_t)radio_get_mode(radio_func);`
- Passing by a third var (but GCC cancel that useless move at compile - not so dumb) :

```
uint32_t r = radio_get_mode(radio_func);
radio_mode = (uint8_t) r;
```

But none of these solutions work.

Since the size optimization (-Os) is needed in first sight to reduce rom usage (and not ram - at this time of my project -)  I found that the workaround gcc option `-fno-short-enums` will let the compiler to use 4 bytes by enum, discarding by the way any overlapping memory in this case.

But, in my opinion, this is a dirty way to hide a real problem here :

- Is GCC not able to correctly handle other return size than 32bit ?
- There is a correct way to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

- I did NOT use `-f-short-enums` at any moment.
- I'm sure that these enum has no value greater than 0xFF
- I have tried to declare `radio_mode` and `radio_func` as `uint8_t` (aka `unsigned char`) : The problem is the same.
- When compiled with `-Os`, Output.map is as follow :

```
Common symbol       size              file
...
radio_mode          0x1               src/radio/radio.o
radio_func          0x1               src/radio/radio.o
...
...
...
Section         address               label
                0x2000319c                radio_state
                0x20003200                radio_mode
                0x20003201                radio_func
                0x20003202                radio_protocol
...
```

The output of the mapfile show clearly that `radio_mode` and `radio_func` is 1 byte wide and at following address.

- When compiled without `-Os`, Output.map show clearly that enums become 4 byte wide (with address padded to 4).
- When compiled with `-Os` and `-fno-short-enums`, do the same things that without `-Os` for all enums (This is why I guess `-Os` implies implicit `-f-short-enums`)
- I will try to provide minimal reproducible example
- My analysis of the problem is that I'm pretty sure it is a compiler bug. For me, this is clearly a memory overlapping. My question is more about the best things to do in order to avoid this - in the "best practice" way.

**EDIT 2**

It is my bad, I have re-tester changing all signature to `uint8_t` (aka `unsigned char`) and it work well.

@Peter Cordes  seems to found the problem here : When using it, `-Os` is partly enabling `-fshort-enums`, getting some parts of GCC to treat it as size 1 and other parts to treat it as size 4.

ASM code using only `uint8_t` is :

```
    ; Same position than before
    7820        ldrb    r0, [r4, #0]
    f7ff ffcd   bl  80098a8 <radio_get_mode>
    4d1e        ldr r5, [pc, #120]  
    7028        strb    r0, [r5, #0]   ; Yes ! GCC use 'strb' and not 'str' like before !
```

To clarify :

- It seems to have compiler bug when using `-Os` and enums. This is bad luck that two enum is at consecutive adresses that overlap.
- Using `-fno-short-enums` in conjonction with `-Os` appear to be a good workaround IMO, since the problem is concerning only enum, and not all 1 byte var at all.

Thanks again.

Comment: According to the _current_ gcc documentation, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html, `-Os` does not _imply_ `-fshort-enums` will be used. It has to be explicitly given. Is that what you've tried ?

Comment: Are you sure `enum eRadioFunction` doesn't have any values > 255 that would stop that enum type from being narrow?  Everything you show is consistent with `sizeof(enum eRadioMode) == 4`, `sizeof(enum eRadioFunction) == 1`, except for the addresses.  Are you really seeing the store to `radio_mode` overlap with `radio_func`?  If so, that sounds like a compiler bug.  Can you provide a [mcve] of this, for example on https://godbolt.org/?

Comment: Note that as `-fshort-enums` changes the ABI, it is not part of any optimisation preset and should be used with care.

Comment: Have you tried giving `radio_mode` the type `unsigned char`?

Comment: Thanks to give me some point, I have edited my question.

Comment: I wonder if `-Os` is *partly* enabling `-fshort-enums`, getting some parts of GCC to treat it as size 1 and other parts to treat it as size 4.  That might explain putting them 1 byte apart but then doing a 4-byte store.  (But not with `unsigned char`, that sounds just plain wrong.  Are you sure all declarations in your code match each other?)  Also BTW, this probably has nothing to do with return values, just assignment.  Have you tried just assigning a constant value to your variable?

Comment: BTW, if you have a bunch of related vars, putting them in a global struct might allow smaller code if the compiler can reuse the same base address for addressing them, instead of loading `0x20003200` and `0x20003201` separately from a literal pool.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I test somes of codes and your wonder about `-Os` was right in my view. Can you put a true response, that I can select as the good one ?

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer including actual test results from something that worked.  I don't have that compiler version available to test with.

Comment: I will do that, thanks again, you have all the credit for it.

Comment: Your problem (if exists) is probably in the code you did show us. It is not possible to reproduce on any ARM compiler I have https://godbolt.org/z/9aSX3k. Voting to close

Comment: The code you write is not the same. I do the update, but with this version, -Os effectively does implicit -fshort-enum.
As you can see, the strb is correctly done here. Not on my version. I'll do a reproducible code tomorrow. (https://godbolt.org/z/hY3uwY)

Comment: @Leviatan ABI not -Os.

Answer (score 0):

ARM port abi defines none-aebi enums to be a variable sized type, linux-eabi to be standards fixed one.

That is the reason the behaviour you observe. It is not related to the optimisation.

In this example you can see how it works. https://godbolt.org/z/-mY_WY

Comment: Thats sound clear, but in your example, we can see that `ARM gcc 7.2.1` and `ARM gcc 7.3` doesn't have the same compilation output with the same options.
In my understanding, 7.3 is not doing the strb (Line 14 on the two output) done in 7.2.1.
We cannot see the size of vars in this output, but I'm pretty sure that the two GCC concider - like u said - 1 byte for the enum. This is my point here.

Comment: Speaking about compiler #3 and #4

Comment: @Leviatan I think you just simple do not understand what is there. The version is not important, The ABI is important. We use ...-none-eabi compilers.  In my example 7.3 is linux-abi 7.2 is none-eabi. You can change it by giving the appropriate command line option - also in example.-+